# Collecting iPhone GPS data

Tags: ios, iphone, csv, gps

So I know that there are all these plug-ins for apps that use GPS data, but **that is not what I am asking**...I wrote a Python library that uses GPS data, and I was wondering if the iPhone stores your GPS data somewhere I can access.

**What I want to do**:

I essentially want to plug my iPhone into my computer, and generate a CSV of GPS data since I always have location on I figured it might store GPS data somewhere.

I have done research and all that comes up are the different ways to access current locations and use locations in apps, but nothing on how to grab all existing GPS data. Is this possible, and if so, where can I find this data?

Comment: That would be a nice feature, but think about security.  No way.  Apple only shares that kind of stuff with the NSA.

Comment: So it does not store the data? I mean if Apple has it, it has to be stored somewhere!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS itself doesn't store GPS data, actually GPS is disabled by default (as it need a lot of energy, to safe battery life). In fact Developers are advised to use gps only when needed, and when not in use gps hardware get off.

Of course, you could build your own app that could store GPS data when running, also in background, and user will be asked permission to use GPS.

Done this, you could upload/use YOUR app data (not system datas that "probably" don't exist, and if exist are not accessible, anyway)

Comment: Unfortunate, but what can you do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this only if you upload your own App to iphone which enables GPS and somehow forwards the GPS data.

But you are limited to following GPS attribtes:
time, latitude, longitude, speed, course, altitude, heading (from compass), horicontalAcc. verticalAcc

(Which is sufficient for most applications)